# Unable to use Firefox v52.0 with Protractor

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor

I am currently having an issue trying to run Protractor tests on my Angular2 site when using GeckoDriver.

I am using Selenium Standalone Server to run my tests and they work in Chrome and IE11 but when I try to run with Firefox I get the following error:

```
Failed: Error while running testForAngular: Error: Permission denied to access property "invoke"
  Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
  System info: host: 'MyPC', ip: '128.87.191.161', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
  Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.UbDrIDtk4eEX, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=52.0, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=12820, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
  Session ID: 6ddf7356-5306-4db6-b6c2-2898406c3193
  Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
  System info: host: 'MyPC', ip: '128.87.191.161', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
  Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.UbDrIDtk4eEX, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=52.0, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=12820, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
  Session ID: 6ddf7356-5306-4db6-b6c2-2898406c3193
      at AbstractExtendedWebDriver.get.timeout.driver.controlFlow.execute.then.then.then.then.then.then.executeAsyncScript_.then (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\protractor\lib\browser.ts:944:27)
      at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1366:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
      at events.EventEmitter.events.EventEmitter.events.EventEmitter.scheduleCallbacks.asyncRun (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2813:27)
      at c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
  From: Task: Run beforeEach in control flow
  From asynchronous test: 
  Error
      at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\specs\login-spec.ts:10:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\specs\login-spec.ts:8:1)
      at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
      at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
      at Array.forEach (native)
```

If I try to run the Firefox tests using directConnet I get another error:

```
[09:37:35] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"b00ee8b7-434e-48e6-83a6-3bca08caba31","value":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"52.0","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:processID":15632,"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.XS9ezQUYQ7um","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"windows_nt","platformVersion":"6.1","rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"page load":300000,"script":30000}}}}
[09:37:35] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"b00ee8b7-434e-48e6-83a6-3bca08caba31","value":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"52.0","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:processID":15632,"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.XS9ezQUYQ7um","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"windows_nt","platformVersion":"6.1","rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"page load":300000,"script":30000}}}}
    at __dirname.execute.request.then.doSend.then.response (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:445:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.js:640:55)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:95:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:194:43)
    at events_1.EventEmitter.run.q.then.then (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:338:29)
    at _fulfilled (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at Promise.then.Q.nextTick.self.promiseDispatch.done (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.__dirname.Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (c:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[09:37:35] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Not sure where to go from here!

**Versions**

- Angular: 2.4.6
- Protractor: 5.1.1
- Selenium Standalone Server: 3.3.1
- GeckoDriver: 0.15.0
- Firefox Browser: 52.0

Comment: You can also use [Zalenium](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/blob/master/docs/usage_examples.md#install-and-start) so don't have to deal with matching versions ;)

Comment: I would open this issue in Protractor to see if they have it working on their side, with the Protractor unit tests.

Comment: Does this work on Chrome? What does your beforeEach method look like in `C:\Projects\Project\ProtractorTests\specs\login-spec.ts:10:5`?

Comment: Exact same problem for me with directConnect:true, but with Firefox version 51.0.1 Did you raise it with Protractor team?

Comment: @RJC - Not raised with Protractor team. Thought I would try here first to see is anyone else was having the same issue and got around it.

Comment: @cnishina - as I stated in my post, this is working in Chrome and IE so i don't think it's a poblem with my spec. But here is the beforeEach from the spec:beforeEach(() => {
        LoginPage.get();
    });

Comment: @cnishina - It calls a method declared in my base-page object which is extended by LoginPage which passed the appropriate URL which finally calls driver.get(url);

Comment: Please edit your original post.

Comment: Found a bug on [Geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/555) which has the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first error.  As far as the second one goes, there is a compatibility issue with geckodriver 0.15.0:  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Permission denied to access property "invoke"` is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/616) in Zone.js, specific to Zone.js and Firefox running with WebDriver. It was fixed in the 0.8.7 release. The issue involves how Zone.js patches the browser, and the only fix is to upgrade.

The `Unable to parse new session response` is also a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4253) with Firefox 52 and `directConnect: true`. Unfortunately, the only solution is to use Selenium Standalone.

Comment: Solved my issue. The problem was with Zone.js. updated to v0.8.10 in my Angular app and the problem disappeared!